# MikroTik HotSpot Walled Garden: iOS ITMS-Services Protocol

Tags: wireless

I am using MikroTik HotSpot.

In our company's portal, We have a link like this:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.test.com/testapp.plist">Download Test App</a>
```

When our iOS users have the Internet, there is no problem to download the iOS test app.

When they are in our HotSpot zone (Before authentication, Without the Internet), they should download the test app too, But they can't.
The popup message "Can not connect to test.com" error occurred on their iOS device.

I've opened ***.test.com** and ***.apple.com** in my Walled Garden list without success.

I've although captured the traffic using Fiddler but there are no URLs exept those above.

I don't know about **itms-services** protocol.

Is there any way to open something in the Walled Garden to allow users to download the test app?

Or is there any way to open other protocols (like itms-services) in the Walled Garden list?

Comment: Unfortunately, MikroTik does not offer optional, paid support for its products, and that is a requirement for questions about hardware on this site. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a client who has internet access, download your app, and simultaneously, run the tool/torch tool to see all connections on wlan interface.

You will be able to see protocol, port, destination if the "itms-service" thing. Then, add a firewall or walled-garden(ip) rule according to that traffic and you should be okay.

Comment: That's not a complete answer for me, but it's a best workaround out there. Thank you.